# integration question about dilogarithm

Tags: integration, special-functions

I want to show that
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=z\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x-z}dx$$

It is the integral of the Bose–Einstein distribution in dilogarithm case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

We have 
\begin{align*}
z\int_0^{+\infty}\frac x{e^x-z}dx
&=z\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-ze^{-x}}dx\\
&=z\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^ne^{-nx}dx\\
&=z\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^n\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-(n+1)x}dx\\
\end{align*}
(to invert the series and the integral we need the dominated convergence theorem, which works here since $|z|<1$). 
Since 
$$\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-(n+1)x}dx=-\frac 1{n+1}\left[xe^{-(n+1)x}\right]_0^{+\infty}+\frac 1{n+1}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(n+1)x}dx=\frac 1{(n+1)^2},$$
we get 
$$z\int_0^{+\infty}\frac x{e^x-z}dx=z\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^j}{j^2}=Li_2(z).$$